# In crimes prosecuted by local authorities, do they take the place off the police or the CPS?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police, prosecution, local-authorities

For example, illegal eviction may be prosecuted by local authorities. In this case, does that mean that they refer the cases after charging to the CPS rather than the relevant police forces? Or that police refer the cases to the LAs after charging instead of referring them to the CPS?